# Building date based on the selection from the user

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, process-builder, workflow

EDIT:

```
CASE( cycle__c, 
'Monthly', ADDMONTHS (selected_date__c, 1),
'Yearly', 

IF(
    AND(
        MONTH(selected_date__c) = 2,
        DAY(selected_date__c) = 29
    ),
    DATE(YEAR(selected_date__c)+ 1, 3,1),
    DATE(YEAR(selected_date__c) + 1, MONTH(selected_date__c), DAY(selected_date__c))
), 
DATE(YEAR(selected_date__c)+ 1, 3,3),
    DATE(YEAR(selected_date__c) + 1, MONTH(selected_date__c), DAY(selected_date__c)),
Null //Default
)
```

I have standard Salesforce page and I have two fields which user will choose from
the first field (`selected_date__c`) is the date and second field (`cycle__c`) is the picklist and based on those two selections, I need to show the `calculate_date__c`

example:

```
selected_date__c = 7/17/2022
cycle__c = Monthly
```

the `calculate_date__c` should be `8/17/2022` (because cycle__c selection was monthly so added one month to it)

another example:

```
selected_date__c = 7/17/2022
cycle__c = Yearly
```

the `calculate_date__c` should be `7/17/2023`

I need to show the `calculate_date__c`, is that possible using formula field or do I need to think of using Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Case` function in formula field to achieve this as follows,

```
CASE( cycle__c, 
'Monthly', ADDMONTHS (selected_date__c, 1),
'Yearly', 

IF(
    AND(
        MONTH(selected_date__c) = 2,
        DAY(selected_date__c) = 29
    ),
    DATE(YEAR(selected_date__c)+ 1, 3,1),
    DATE(YEAR(selected_date__c) + 1, MONTH(selected_date__c), DAY(selected_date__c))
),
piclist value 3 , Outcome/Result 3, //you can add more additional logic on here
Null //Default
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: great, so I add another option something like `simiyearly` next to the `yearly` but it throws an error `Incorrect number of parameters for function 'CASE()'. Expected 6, received 7 (Related field: Formula)`

Comment: If you adding another one option means please add into the correct format, as follows,
`value 3, Result 3` before the `default` option.

Comment: what is the value 3, result 3, add the logic after the if condition you mean? or can you edit the answer please?

Comment: `add the logic after the if condition you mean?`  - Yes, I have updated the answer now. Please Check.

Comment: I updated my question please see if this make sense but i'm getting syntax error though.

Comment: Sorry, You're confused I think. See my answer, `Piclist Value 3` points a new piclist value from `cycle__c` custom field. And `Outcome/Result 3` Points the formula which need to come for the 3rd piclist value. Pleases let me know if you get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134178/discussion-between-nick-kahn-and-mohanraj).